# Help understanding notation around generalized inverses of distribution functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, notation

I am trying to understand this excerpt from Beran (1984) - an old paper on the statistics of the bootstrap:
[image: Beran (1984)]

I don't understand how it can ever be the case that $c_{n, L} < c_{n, U}$. Isn't it the case that, by definition $c_{n, L} \geq c_{n, U}$, since distribution functions are always non-decreasing? In fact, I don't understand how we can ever have $c_{n, L} \neq c_{n, U}$. But if $c_{n, L} = c_{n, U}$ always, then this write-up seems strange.

As I see it, both of these things are equivalent to the "generalized inverse" commonly used for distribution functions, which is usually defined similarly to $c_{n, L}$ here (i.e. $F^{-1}(1-\alpha) = c_{n,L}(\alpha)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution function (aka cumulative distribution function, probability distribution function, cdf) is always non-decreasing but can be constant on intervals.  Such as, the cdf for a Bernoulli random variable, for which, say, $$F(x)=P(X\le x)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if }x<0\\1-p&\text{if }0\le x<1\\1&\text{if }x\ge1.\end{cases}$$
Apply Beran's recipe in the case that $\alpha=p$ and you will see that the two $c_n$ numbers differ.

The underlying random variable need not be discrete.  Such as a Bernoulli rv plus an independent uniform on the range $[0,1/2]$; the resulting sum is supported on $[0,1/2]\cup[1,3/2]$, and if $\alpha$ corresponds to the probability of $[0,1/2]$, the two $c_n$ numbers will again differ.

If the graph of $F$ has horizontal segments on which $F$ is constant, the inverse of $F$ will have jump discontinuities.  The two $c_n$ numbers are the left- and right hand limits of $F^{-1}(1-\alpha)$.